# Expected value of the absolute standardized t distribution

Tags: expected-value, t-distribution, absolute-value

What is the expected value of the absolute standardized t-distribution - i.e.,:
$E(|X|)$, where $X$ has the standardized t-distribution?

Comment: There are two close votes now, "needs details or clarity". I don't quite see what is unclear about this question. Could close-voters please comment on what clarification they would like to see?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [whuber's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8482/1352) to [Standardized Student's-t distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8466/1352), the density of the standardized $t$ distribution on $\nu$ degrees of freedom is

$$f(x) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu + 1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(\nu-2)}} \left[1+\frac{x^2}{\nu-2}\right]^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}.$$

(Note that we need $\nu>2$ so we have two moments to standardize.)

Thus, your expectation is

$$ \begin{align*}
  E(|X|) & = 2\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx \\
& = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu + 1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi(\nu-2)}} \int_0^\infty x\left[1+\frac{x^2}{\nu-2}\right]^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}\,dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu + 1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi(\nu-2)}} \left(-\frac{\nu-2}{\nu-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu-2}\right)^{\frac{1-\nu}{2}}\bigg|_0^\infty \\
& = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu + 1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})}  \frac{\sqrt{\nu-2}}{\nu-1}
\end{align*} $$
by [a rather simple integral evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*%281%2Bx%5E2%2F%28n-2%29%29%5E%28-%28n%2B1%29%2F2%29).

I like sanity checking calculations like these using simulation, and it seems to check out:

```
> df <- 10
> nn <- 1e6
> 
> sims <- rt(nn,df)/(sqrt(df/(df-2)))# standardize by the variance
> mean(sims)
[1] -0.0006262779
> var(sims)
[1] 0.9995302
> 
> mean(abs(sims))
[1] 0.7732408
> 2/sqrt(pi)*gamma((df+1)/2)/gamma(df/2)*sqrt(df-2)/(df-1)
[1] 0.773398
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan!

Comment: +1. This works for any $\nu \gt 2;$ it is not necessary that $\nu \ge 3.$

Comment: @whuber: good point, I edited that into the post.